# How to know if the toolshelf/properties/header is ON/OFF with python?

Tags: python, scripting

i'd like to have a boolean return value with thoses three toggle operator

```
bpy.ops.view3d.toolshelf()
bpy.ops.view3d.properties()
bpy.ops.screen.header()
```

id like to toggle them only if they are 'ON', but i don't see any way i can do that

Answer (score 0):

there's no official way to know, you can just know, i just found a trick with the interface region width

```
import bpy

bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'VIEW_3D'
area = bpy.context.area

for region in area.regions:
    if region.type == 'TOOLS':
        if region.width == 1: 
            print("toolshelf closed")
        else:
            print("toolshelf open")
    elif region.type =='UI':
        if region.width == 1: 
            print("properties closed")
        else:
            print("properties open")
    elif region.type =='HEADER':
        if region.width == 1: 
            print("header closed")
        else:
            print("header open")
```